# Exporting two schemas of the same database at the same time

Tags: database, oracle

How do I export two schemas of the same database at the same time in Oracle?

The intention is not to have any production server downtime during the database migration.

Comment: are we exporting or are we migrating? there's usually never any downtime, but your migration bit makes me think what you're really asking is how do we move databases to a new machine and not have any downtime...which would lead to using a replication technology like GoldenGate